# How do I check that an SQL insertion didn't work because of a Primary Key violation in Access VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am looping through an array and filling a table in Access with its values through SQL INSERT INTO statements:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(vData)
    quote = Chr(34) 'Quote string

    'SQL string
    strSql = "INSERT INTO " & TABLE_NAME & " VALUES (" & _
        quote & vData(i, 1) & quote & "," & quote & vData(i, 2) & quote & "," & vData(i, 3) & "," & _
        quote & vData(i, 4) & quote & "," & vData(i, 5) & "," & vData(i, 6) & "," & _
        vData(i, 7) & "," & vData(i, 8) & "," & vData(i, 9) & "," & _
        vData(i, 10) & "," & vData(i, 11) & "," & vData(i, 12) & _
        "," & vData(i, 13) & ")"

'So we don't get a "are you sure" message on every insertion
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Next
```

Occasionally it's possible that a record can't be inserted due to a primary key violation, in which case it is completely appropriate to just ignore it (which is what will automatically happen).
However, I would like to - at the very least - present a message to the user letting them know that the item could not be inserted, but I can't find any corresponding error codes that I can use to detect such an event.

I also don't want to turn warnings off because I'll get a "Are you sure you want to append" message on every insertion.

Any ideas on how to detect this error in VBA?

Comment: Use `CreateQueryDef` and `Parameters` to allow the use of `On Error` handlers and to avoid SQL Injection vulnerability

Comment: @Stavr00 thanks, I actually didn't know about CreateQueryDef. Very useful.